# Problems getting weight sensor data to csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, raspberry-pi, scale

I just built a raspberry-pi scale. The code (below) works well. After tare is done, it accurately weighs the objects and simultaneously displays time/date and weight values on the rasp-pi screen. However it doesn't do anything to the csv file. No names on columns, no data. Oddly, the code runs and shows no errors. Could please anyone see what is wrong?
Thanks!
Paulina

```
#! /usr/bin/python2
import csv
import datetime
import time

#tare and use the scale
EMULATE_HX711=False

referenceUnit = 1

if not EMULATE_HX711:
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    from hx711 import HX711
else:
    from emulated_hx711 import HX711

def cleanAndExit():
    print("Cleaning...")

    if not EMULATE_HX711:
        GPIO.cleanup()

    print("Bye!")
    sys.exit()

hx = HX711(5, 6)

hx.set_reading_format("MSB", "MSB")

#CALCULATE THE REFFERENCE UNIT
hx.set_reference_unit(1903.3090)

hx.reset()

hx.tare()

print("Tare done! Add weight now...")
#measure weight and write it to csv
while True:
    try:
       # gets the weight. 
        val = hx.get_weight(5)
       # problems here, doesn't write to csv 
        with open('/home/pi/Desktop/sensor2.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
            writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    # Write a header row with the name of each column.
            writer.writerow(['Time', 'weight'])
    # loop generating new sensor readings every and writing them
    # to the CSV file.
            while True:
        # Make some sensor data.
                reading_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                weight = hx.get_weight(5)   
        # Print out the data and write to the CSV file.
                print('Time: {0} weight: {1}'.format(reading_time, weight))
                writer.writerow([reading_time, weight])
        hx.power_down()
        hx.power_up()
        time.sleep(0.05)

    except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
        cleanAndExit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check permissions on the folders and files as that is likely the issue. I ran your code (without the scale part see below) on my RPi 3B+ and it worked perfectly. Ensure the file is writable as well as the folder. My sensor file did not previously exist and was created and populated as expected. This is what I tested:

```
    #! /usr/bin/python2
    import csv
    import datetime
    import time

    with open('sensor.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow(['Time', 'weight'])
        reading_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        weight = 150
        writer.writerow([reading_time, weight])
```

The content of sensor.csv is:

> Time,weight
> 2020-06-06 04:59:16.840512,150